# How to delete group of rows if in certain column value doesn't met the condition?

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

For example, here is the table (df):

| Number | Code | Action | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7271 | 1 | send | 2021-10-20 13:12:18 |
| 7271 | 1 | get | 2021-10-20 13:12:20 |
| 7271 | 1 | take | 2021-10-20 13:12:21 |
| 7271 | 1 | reply | 2021-10-20 13:12:25 |
| 7271 | 1 | send: | 2021-10-20 13:15:18 |
| 7271 | 1 | get | 2021-10-20 13:15:20 |
| 7271 | 5 | take | 2021-10-20 13:15:21 |
| 7271 | 5 | reply | 2021-10-20 13:15:25 |

and I want to delete group of rows, where in column 'Action' string "send" has no ":" (colon).
I mean, I want to have a table where in column 'Action', string 'send' consist a colon and also that row's group. By row's group, I mean rows with the same Number and Datetime(in some interval).
Also, Numbers can repeat but with different DateTime.
There are over 100 000 data.

New table should look like this:

| Number | Priority | Action | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7271 | 1 | send: | 2021-10-20 13:15:18 |
| 7271 | 1 | get | 2021-10-20 13:15:20 |
| 7271 | 5 | take | 2021-10-20 13:15:21 |
| 7271 | 5 | reply | 2021-10-20 13:15:25 |

P.S: string 'send' with a colon ('send:') means that a client with a certain number is replied.

Comment: I was thinking like: i) create new column where string 'send'  (no colon) is True.
ii) then delete a rows (if new column is True) and (if a Number which corresponds True value is the same across rows) and (if DateTime are within 2 min of True value). If this 3 conditions met, I'll delete the row. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean mask:

```
mask = df.loc[df['Action'].str.startswith('send'), 'Action'] \
         .str.endswith(':').reindex(df.index).ffill()

df = df[mask]
print(df)

# Output:
   Number  Code Action             DateTime
4    7271     1  send:  2021-10-20 13:15:18
5    7271     1    get  2021-10-20 13:15:20
6    7271     5   take  2021-10-20 13:15:21
7    7271     5  reply  2021-10-20 13:15:25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups by values after `send` by compare with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with cumualtive sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and filter only groups if `send:` in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m1 = df['Action'].str.startswith('send')
m2 = df['Action'].eq('send:')
s = m1.cumsum()

df = df[s.isin(s[m2])]
print (df)
   Number  Code Action             DateTime
4    7271     1  send:  2021-10-20 13:15:18
5    7271     1    get  2021-10-20 13:15:20
6    7271     5   take  2021-10-20 13:15:21
7    7271     5  reply  2021-10-20 13:15:25
```